# How can I apply styles to each character separately when they are in one div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to give a different background CSS style per letter for one of my divs, e.g.:

```
<div class="hello">1999</div>
```

so there is a counter-like background behind every word. For reference:

[image]

How can I do that without separating the div classes one by one?

Comment: Please use [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function.

Comment: @RobinSingh i used pure wordpress,so i cant really call a variable with str_split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this after the page loads, you can use JavaScript

Something like this

```js
const div = document.querySelector(".hello")
div.innerHTML = div.textContent.split("").map(letter => `<span ${letter.trim() === "" ? "" : 'class="block"'}>${letter}</span>`).join("")
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">      1999     </div>
```

Emojis:

```css
.hello { font-size: 50px; letter-spacing: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="hello">1️⃣9️⃣9️⃣9️⃣</div>
```

Comment: I don't see a JS tag with the post

Comment: @Gerard the way the question is phrased, doesn’t give much of an impression OP really knows what’s possible using CSS alone, and what isn’t, regarding their requirement. And they rejected a suggestion to split the content using PHP already, even though that _was_ tagged. So I’d say JS is probably a _valid_ solution, considering their restrictions.

Comment: I also assumed OP wanted something to plug into their page without messing with a wordpress theme or PHP

Comment: @mplungjan it works kinda, https://ibb.co/gyYCK6R, do you know how to make it so that only the numbers get the background image, sorry to bother you guys its my first time asking and im pretty new to wordpress, i prefer coding in visual studio tbh, thanks!

Comment: The class 'block' is unneeded. In CSS just apply `.hello >span{}`

Comment: @JonathanEdward Sorry I missed your question.Is it not because you have `>    1999      <` instead of `>1999<` in the div?

Comment: I updated the answer to only add the class to the actual numbers

Comment: @mplungjan hey, just letting you know it works, i figure you can just specify each span with CSS Child method, so what i did is just typed .block:nth-child(8) and go from there. Thank you for the javascript solution even though i didn't tag it, script kiddie mistakes, ciao!

Answer (score 3):

You can play with background and monospace font:

```css
.hello {
  display: table;
  margin:20px auto;
  font-size: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5ch;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #000 0 calc(1.5ch - 10px), transparent 0 1.5ch)
    0 0/calc(100% - 11px) 100% no-repeat;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">1999</div>

<div class="hello">19990</div>

<div class="hello">333</div>
```

With some CSS variables:

```css
.hello {
  --c:black; /* color */
  --s:0.5ch; /* space between letter*/
  --b:10px;  /* transparent border*/

  display: table;
  margin:20px auto;
  font-size: 100px;
  letter-spacing: var(--s);
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, var(--c) 0 calc(1ch + var(--s) - var(--b)), transparent 0 calc(1ch + var(--s)))
    0 0/calc(100% - var(--s)/2 - 1px) 100% no-repeat;
  padding-left: calc((var(--s) - var(--b))/2);
  transform:translateX(calc(var(--s)/3)); /* rectify the centring */
}

html {
 background:#f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">1999</div>

<div class="hello" style="--c:red;--b:5px;--s:1ch;font-size:80px;">19990</div>

<div class="hello" style="--c:green;--b:20px;--s:2ch">333</div>
```