# CSS - Style each word of span

Tags: html, css

I have the task of styling a countdown that someone has made for us, but the tricky part is that it's being rendered in a span like so:

`<span>D H m</span>`

I can't really change the countdown code and they want me to create borders and background for each set of numbers in the countdown like the image below.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve that with pure css?

Comment: no, you would need to wrap each part in it's own span - unless your words were a fixed length, then you could just use a background image, but then you probably wouldn't be able to space the words correctly

Comment: You need to use 3 elements. CSS can't style single words. It's not just about borders (you can maybe render it using pseudoelements on this span and parent), you aren't able to make number groups with this size of gap between, etc.

Comment: Can't you just ask that 'someone' to put the individual time-elements to individual spans?

Comment: Can you show us the surrounding HTML and CSS? It looks as though the space for the numbers is fixed, is it?

Comment: a good starting point here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66133217/8620333

Comment: As you have numerals it makes sense to use a monospaced font and you can do calculations in CSS ch units and use linear, radial gradients to draw the boxes and other background.

Answer (score 0):

Mayeb with the help of `box-shadow` and `pseudo` elements. you can achieve something like this.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color: #0f0;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow:
    2px 2px 0px #000 inset,
    -2px -2px 0px #000 inset,
    4px 4px 0px #0f0 inset,
    -4px -4px 0px #0f0 inset;
}
span::before {
  content: '';
  background: #0f0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 21px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  width: 2px;
}
span::after {
  content: '';
  background: #0f0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 21px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<span>D H m</span>
```

Or else you would have to go with a background image.